# Translate function not returning relevant string in amazon redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use a simple Translate function to replace "-" in a 23 digit string. The example of one such string is "1049477-1623095-2412303" The expected outcome of my query should be 104947716230952412303

The list of all "1049477-1623095-2412303" is present in a single column "table1". The name of the column is "data"

My query is

```
Select TRANSLATE(t.data, '-', '')
from table1 as t
```

However, it is returning 104947716230952000000 as the output.

At first, I thought it is an overflow error since the resulting integer is 20 digit so I also tried to use following

```
SELECT CAST(TRANSLATE(t.data,'-','') AS VARCHAR)
from table1 as t
```

but this is not working as well.

Please suggest a way so that I could have my desirable output

Comment: Can you show the actual part of the code where you do this? Is `t.data` really defined as string or is it a numeric vakue with some formatting applied?

Comment: I am uploading the list of all these string using a data portal in a temporary table. There I have mentioned that the column values are of VARCHAR Data Type. This is an input which is required to create a temp table. At this point of time, I am using the above-mentioned code snippet only.(The one without Cast)

Comment: Can you some examples what is returned when you run `select t.data, trim(t.data) ...`?

Comment: have you tried `REPLACE` instead of `TRANSLATE`?

Comment: @dnoeth, Tried Trim(t.data) and t.data. It is giving 1049477-1623095-2412303 for both

Comment: @AlexYes, Yes tried that as well. It is also giving me similar result as Translate

Comment: Then there's an implixit or explicit conversion to a numeric value, probably a FLOAT.

Comment: @dnoeth any ideas on how to tackle it?

Comment: No, sorry. If there's a cast `TRANSLATE(t.data, '-', 'A')` should fail :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

This code:

```
select translate('1049477-1623095-2412303', '-', '')
```

is going to return:

```
'104947716230952412303'
```

The return value is a string, not a number.

There is no way that it can return '104947716230952000000'.  I could only imagine that happening if somehow the value is being converted to a numeric or bigint type.

Answer (score 0):

Try `regexp_replace()`

Taking your own example, execute:

```
select regexp_replace('[string / column_name]','-');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieve [RPAD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LPAD.html) try below code.

```
             SELECT RPAD(TRANSLATE(CAST(t.data as VARCHAR),'-','') ,20,'00000000000000000000')
```